# UIAlertView Not showing from helper class

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, static

Im trying to use a method in a function helper class:

**Function Helper:**

```
+(void)ShowAlertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:title
                                     message:message
                                    delegate:nil
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                           otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

It's a static function, it only works when I call it directly from a `ViewController`

But what I need is to call this function from another class (not a Viewcontroller), then it does not show most of the time.

The class has function like this:

**Api Helper:**

```
if (![FunctionHelper IsConnected]) {
   [FunctionHelper 
          ShowAlertViewWithTitle:@"Network connection error" 
                         message:@"Error!"];
}
```

EDIT:

It seems that the issue is that I call it asynchronously. How can I force the method to call it on the main thread?

Comment: `+(void) ShowUIAlertView:(NSString *)title :(NSString *)message` this is a bad method name and parameters. It should be something like `+ (void)ShowAlertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message`

Comment: Are you sure that you call `ShowUIAlertView` in main thread?

Comment: popeye thanks for the advice, I will rename, @Cy-4AH you right I was calling this function asynchronously. how can I force it to run on main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+ (void)ShowAlertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:title
                                         message:message
                                        delegate:nil
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 I have also amended to the method name to match in the question as the OP has changed it based on my recommendation.

Comment: this worked for me without needing any tap logic for OK buttton, but now i need to implement a logic for OK button, and i am calling this helper function from a UIViewcontroller subclass like so

[[Helper sharedInstance] ShowAlertViewWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"foo"];

Comment: @Edwin, you can add UIAlertView's delegate as method argument or use some other delegate for your logic.